# Cakephp3 : using another model in a controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I started an app with CakePHP3 and i need to record some users's actions. So, I have migrated my log structure, I have baked my controller & model and now, I try to get a log when a user log in.

I updated my UsersController like this:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use App\Model\Table\LogsTable;
use App\Model\Entity\User;
use App\Model\Entity\Log;

class UsersController extends AppController {

    public function login(){
      $this->viewBuilder()->layout('external');
      $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
      if($this->request->is('post')){
        $user = $this->Auth->identify();
        if($user){
          //DOING : enregistrement valide$log = new Log();
            $log->user_id = 1;
            $log->action = 'lorem ipsum';
            $log->target_user = 0;
            $log->target_object = 0;
            $log->comment = 'test';
            $logs = new LogsTable();
            $logs->save($log);

          $this->Auth->setUser($user);
          if($this->Auth->user('security') == 'admin'){
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'admin_index']);
          }else{
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
          }
        }
        //TODO : enregistrement faux
        $this->Flash->error(__('Email or password are wrong.'));
      }
      $this->set(compact('user'));
      $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
    }

}
```

But it doesn't work, I have the error message for the save() :

Error: Call to a member function transactional() on a non-object

Any ideas?

Comment: `use App\Controller\AnotherController;` in a controller, `$this->save($log);` in a controller and `$logs = new LogsTable();` anywhere at all are 3 examples of things you never do in CakePHP. "it doesn't work" is not helpful to readers. Before doing anything else it would be a good idea to look at the docs, the level of problem you currently have is very basic, and covered by the blog tutorial.

Comment: In the tutorial, there is categories who are link to the articles with the foreign  key. What I want to do is different : this is the log who is connected to the users. So the foreign key is in the LogsTable.

Comment: `What I want to do is different` your scenario is identical, only the names change.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This way

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

$logs = TableRegistry::get('LogsTable');
$logs->save($log);
```

[more info](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#the-query-object)

EDIT since 3.6 you should use

```
use Cake\ORM\TableLocator

$articles = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Articles', [
    'className' => 'App\Custom\ArticlesTable',
    'table' => 'my_articles',
    'connection' => $connectionObject,
    'schema' => $schemaObject,
    'entityClass' => 'Custom\EntityClass',
    'eventManager' => $eventManager,
    'behaviors' => $behaviorRegistry
]);
```

[more info here](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/table-objects.html#using-the-tablelocator)

Comment: Thanks a lot! With : $logs = TableRegistry::get('Logs');, this is working fine!

Comment: If the models are associated it's not necessary to use the TableRegistry at all `$this->Users->Logs` is the LogsTable, it doesn't matter what kind of association it is: [Similarly in your controller you can access an associated model simply by following your model associations](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#relationship-types)

Comment: deprecated since 3.6.0 (use `TableLocator::get()` instead)