# Function from Model not recognized in CakePhp 3

Tags: php, cakephp, model-view-controller, cakephp-3.0, shopping-cart

I am just making sure if I am making any mistakes. I am trying to access a function of a Model(Cart) from a different Controller(Product).

I got idea about this from a forum, i think it is right way to do. But i am  getting this error

```
Unknown method addToCart
```

Can you please let me know where did i make mistake?

**ProductController:**

```
    public function initialize(){
         parent::initialize();
        $table =  $this->loadModel('Cart');// this works fine
        }

      public function addit() {
            $table->addToCart();

      }
```

**Model:**

```
 class CartTable extends Table{
      public function addToCart(){
        echo "hello from model";
       }

    }
```

Is there anything i need to do more? I did not find that helps me with this.So please wise people help me out.Thank you :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp3 : using another model in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030044/cakephp3-using-another-model-in-a-controller)

Comment: $table will only be assigned in the `initialize` function, not in the `addit` function. It would work if you'd rewrite it to `$this->table = $this->loadModel('Cart')` and then call it with `$this->table->addToCart()` in the `addit` function. However, this is not how you should do this. See the answers.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this as following.

```
public function initialize(){
     parent::initialize();
     $this->loadModel('Cart');// this works fine
    }

  public function addit() {
       $this->Cart->addToCart();
  }
```

In cakephp 3 you can also lodel model by TableRegistery Just use this.

```
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
```

Before using  put this line on use section of controller

```
public function addit() {
    $cart_table = TableRegistry::get('Cart');

       $cart_table->addToCart();
}
```

Comment: $this->loadModel('Cart') and TableRegistry::get('Cart') do the same things.

Comment: @Sehdev i know very well that. I just suggest him alternative approach to loadModel.

Comment: @Sehdev In the default configuration they essentially do, but `loadModel()` is more abstract, and it can load non-table repositories.

Comment: V@Sehdev, @vishnu-singh Thank you for your suggestions. I have already tried those edits...didn't help. I tried it again. Still not helping ....:(

Comment: @vins please pr TableRegistery object and share let check error in code.

Comment: @vishnusingh sorry friend i didnt quite get you... you want to see my code ...is it what you are saying?

Comment: @vins load your model using  $cart_table = TableRegistry::get('Cart'); and print $cart_table and share. So we can check if your model defination is correct.

Comment: @vishnusingh there you go: Controller :   <?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\ORM\Table;

class ProductsController extends AppController
{
   public function initialize(){
     parent::initialize();
    $table =  $this->loadModel('Cart');
     }


  public function addit() {
      // $cart_table = TableRegistry::get('Cart');
         if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          $this->Cart->addToCart(); } }}

Comment: @vishnusingh here comes the model: <?php
namespace App\Model\Table;
namespace App\Http\Session;

use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\ORM\RulesChecker;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Cake\Network\Session;
use Cake\Core\Configure;

class CartTable extends Table
{
  public function addToCart(){
    $cart_table = TableRegistry::get('Cart');
    echo "hello from model";
  }


}
The error is unknown function addToCart()

Comment: @vishnusingh because of this haven't been able to move ahead... :(

Comment: @vins namespace App\Http\Session is extra in you model class.  Also you dont have need to use  $cart_table = TableRegistry::get('Cart'); in same model.

Comment: @vishnusingh thanks...i was trying whatever possible :( yet unsolved

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your model in the method, and you do not need to assign it to a var.

```
    public function initialize(){
        parent::initialize();
    }

   public function addit() {
        $this->loadModel('Cart');
        $this->Cart->addToCart();
   }
```

This should get you up and running.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem...

The solutions is very simple, just add this code in your model class :

```
namespace App\Model\Table;
```

So, your model will be like this :

```
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class CartTable extends Table{
  public function addToCart(){
    echo "hello from model";
  }
}
```

I hope this will help those who are having the same problem.
Thanks