# How to Add to Table from Another Controller Cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm new to cakephp3. I would like to know if it is possible to add a new entry form controller1 to table2.

It is a login form. So I would like to authenticate first whether the user is registered, then after authenticating, I would like to save the details to another table.

```php
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function login()
    {
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
        if($this->request->is(['post']))
        {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if($user)
            {
                $logs = TableRegistry::get('AttendsTable');
                $log->username = 'lorem ipsum';
                $log->datenow = '2018-11-10';
                $log->tin = '12:42:00';
                $log->tout ='12:42:00';
                $logs->save($log);
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                $this->redirect(['action'=>'index']);
            }
        }
    }
```

I am getting an error:

> "Argument 1 passed to Cake\ORM\Table::save() must implement interface Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface, instance of stdClass given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\TimeStamps\src\Controller\UsersController.php on line 32"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030044/cakephp3-using-another-model-in-a-controller

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp3 : using another model in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030044/cakephp3-using-another-model-in-a-controller)

Comment: I have solved this with the help of the documentation from https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the `Model->save()` function expects an entity. In your snippet `$log` is not defined first, so PHP just makes it a `stdClass` (gotta love high-level programming :p).

Something like this should work:

```
$logs = TableRegistry::get('AttendsTable');
$log = $logs->newEntity([
    'username' => 'lorem ipsum',
    'datenow' => '2018-11-10',
    // ...
]);

$logs->save($log);
```

Moreover, I've heard say it's better to use `$this->loadModel()` instead of `TableRegistry::get()`:

```
$this->loadModel('ExternalModel');

// Now available:
$this->ExternalModel->//...
```

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Loading Additional Models](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models)**

Comment: Up for this. I used the loadModel(). Big thanks! Also to the documentation. I guess I just really need to read all the contents of the documentation before asking a question. :D