# How can i load model into the different controller

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0

I have two controllers UsersController and UserRolesController. I want load the UserRoles model into my UsersController for fetching the value of the users with their roles. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37031325/4248328

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cakephp3 : using another model in a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37030044/cakephp3-using-another-model-in-a-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in multiple ways.

- In your **UsersController**, put `$this->loadModel('UserRoles')` before the code and use it like `$this->UserRoles->whatevermethod`.
- Inject `TableRegistry` as `use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;` ( if not already injected ) at the top of **UsersController**.

  Use the model like : `TableRegistry::get('UserRoles)->whatevermethod`

Comment: Assuming associations are set up correctly, you can probably also use `$this->Users->UserRoles` to access this directly without any of the other methods.